# Two different ways of labeling in QGIS Layouter

Tags: qgis, labeling, layouts

I've made a map with points and labels related to those points. In one area, the points are very dense, therefore, I'd prefer to create one small scale map and in the corner a large scale map, to get more detail.

Now, my problem is that - for the dense part - labels should only be put on the large scale map, for the other points, the label should be present on the small scale map.

How would you solve this?

I can choose labels for one map (like in: [How to only show labels for an arbitrary selection of items?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18630/how-to-only-show-labels-for-an-arbitrary-selection-of-items)), make a layouter for the map, and subsequently do the same for the other map. But than, if you want to change something to the first, labels are updated again to the actual state of your qgis project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the points which will be displayed in the smaller map viewer and create a new layer with the same properties as the parent layer. display the over the parent layer. label them via the Easy labeling pluggin and move them around accordingly and set a scale dependent visability for them to match the smaller box. therefore the wider view will see all the areas with the labels displayed for the "less dense" are and the smaller map viewer will show the "more dense area" with labels.